# Event listener on Docker using volume mount not working

Tags: python, docker, events, python-watchdog

Some folder is mounted using:

```
docker run -it  C:\Users\User\Documents\project\input:/app/input/ project:latest
```

In the container a Python a `watchdog.observers` instance is running to detect if new files are added to the host folder. These files end up in the Docker container via the volume mount.
The file created event trigger does not reach the Docker container. I think this is strange because in the Docker container events are also happening right?

When I run my code locally and not in Docker the eventlistener it is working.

Does event listening work in my context?

main.py

```
from watch import ImagesWatcher

if __name__ == '__main__':
    src_path = "/app/input/"
    ImagesWatcher(src_path).run()
```

watch.py

```
import sys
import time

from watchdog.observers import Observer
from ImagesEventHandler import ImagesEventHandler


class ImagesWatcher:
    def __init__(self, src_path):
        self.__src_path = src_path
        self.__event_handler = ImagesEventHandler()
        self.__event_observer = Observer()


    def run(self):
        self.start()
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            self.stop()

    def start(self):
        self.__schedule()
        self.__event_observer.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.__event_observer.stop()
        self.__event_observer.join()

    def __schedule(self):
        self.__event_observer.schedule(
            self.__event_handler,
            self.__src_path,
            recursive=True
        )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    src_path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    ImagesWatcher(src_path).run()
```

imagesEventHandler.py

```
from watchdog.events import RegexMatchingEventHandler

class ImagesEventHandler(RegexMatchingEventHandler):
    THUMBNAIL_SIZE = (128, 128)
    IMAGES_REGEX = [r".*[^_thumbnail]\.jpg$"]

    def __init__(self):
        # self.Analyzer = Analyzer()
        super().__init__(self.IMAGES_REGEX)

    def on_created(self, event):
        self.process(event)

    def process(self, event):
        print("DETECTED")
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6
RUN pip install watchdog
ADD . .
WORKDIR /app/
RUN main.py
```

Comment: Maybe you can share a simple code which others could easy reproduce...

Comment: You should not expect that the file change from the host is reflected directly in the container. Even on a Linux host the inode change is not reported in every constellation. On a Windows host there is an additional layer of virtualization in between and Windows file systems don't use inodes as Linux does.

Comment: So I am a little curious about any difference if I `touch file in the volume on windows` V.S. `touch file in the volume on linux container directly`?

Comment: The inodes are indeed different.

Comment: @atline I've added some code.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague recommended me the following: https://github.com/merofeev/docker-windows-volume-watcher